# Chrome & Safari JQuery Bug with Animate and Show/Hide

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, jquery-animate, show

I have a sidebar slider that's working fine in FF and IE.  On click of the div, the sidebar slides out; click again and it slides back.  In Chrome and Safari, however, it works fine the first time (animate width out and animate width back), but the second time, the div that should slide out instead partially appears underneath the div to click.

I've created a very simple example of the problem.  Here is the javascript:

```
var slider_state = 'hidden';

function reveal_slider()
{
$('#reveal_div').animate({width:500});
slider_state = 'shown';
}

function hide_slider ()
{
slider_state = 'hidden';
$('#reveal_div').animate({width:0}, function(){
    $('#reveal_div').hide();
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#slider_trigger').click(function(){
    if (slider_state == 'hidden')
        {
        reveal_slider();
        }  
        else
        {
        hide_slider();
        }
    });
});
```

And css:

```
#slider_container
        {
        position:fixed;
        top:350px;
        right:0px;
        z-index:21;
        }
    #slider_trigger
        {
        float:left;
        width:35px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:yellow;
        }
    #reveal_div
        {
        float:left;
        height:200px;
        display:none;
        background-color:blue;
        border:3px black solid;
        }
```

And html:

```
<body>
<div id='slider_container'>
    <div id='slider_trigger'>
        Click
    </div>  
    <div id='reveal_div' >
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Thanks very much in advance for the help.

Comment: a JSFiddle would actually be helpful.  Is there a reason you aren't using the Toggle functionality out of curiosity?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for viewing.  Looks like MobyD's suggestion (in comments) held the key, which was to use toggle(), or at least show() on the div to be revealed, before animating its width.  Appreciate the help.